# Update shopping cart Button - Magento Cart

Tags: magento, button, cart, user-friendly

I was wondering to make easy for customers on checkout that:

Every time that user changes or switches the number of quantity on Magento's cart page, at the same time appears the button "update shopping cart" down the field of quantity.

Because some users change the numbers and sometimes forget to click on update shopping cart, so how can I do it?

Example: User 1 enters on store, add to cart 1 quantity of product X, then on cart changes to 2 and instantly appears down the quantity field the button of update.

PS: I'm using Magento version 1.8.1

Thanks guys,

Comment: You should probably use prototype or jQuery for this. You can bind an onchange-event to all quantity-inputfields and show (or move) an update-cart button next to the appropriate inputfield. How this should be done exactly, is opinion-based and dependent on the template you are using...

Comment: could you give an example @RichardBernards ?